# dictionary containing arrays and matrices to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a dictionary `a` that looks like this:

```
a = {}
a['first_variable']=np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
a['second_variable']=np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10]])
```

As you can see some keys contain an array, other a matrix...

Given this  dictionary, I would like to create a dataframe that looks like this

```
a_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(columns=['first_variable','second_variable_col1','second_variable_col2'])
a_dataframe['first_variable']=np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
a_dataframe['second_variable_col1']=np.array([1,3,5,7,9])
a_dataframe['second_variable_col2']=np.array([2,4,6,8,10])
```

This should be done in an automatic fashion...ie taking the names from the dictionary keys and in case of a matrix add col1, col2, etc...

Can you help me?
Thanks

Comment: Can you please put your side problem in a different question?

Comment: sure! it s here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43635629/list-of-dictionaries-containing-arrays-and-matrices-to-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with list comprehension and `DataFrame` constructor, last create `columns` from `MultiIndex` in columns:

```
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(a[x]) for x in a], keys=a.keys(), axis=1)
df.columns = ['{}{}'.format(x[0], x[1]) for x in df.columns]
print (df)
   second_variable0  second_variable1  first_variable0
0                 1                 2                1
1                 3                 4                2
2                 5                 6                3
3                 7                 8                4
4                 9                10                5
```

Comment: thank you! I have added to my question a side problem, ie what if the original dictionary is a list of dictionaries...

Comment: @ScottBoston - Thanks you.

Comment: I have asked it in a separate/new question...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43635629/list-of-dictionaries-containing-arrays-and-matrices-to-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
a = {}
a['first_variable']=np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
a['second_variable']=np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10]])

#Use a double list comprehension to construct both data and column names in one go.
df = pd.DataFrame({'{}_col{}'.format(k,i):e for k,v in a.items() 
                      for i,e in enumerate(np.asarray(v).T.reshape(-1,5))})
print(df)
   first_variable_col0  second_variable_col0  second_variable_col1
0                    1                     1                     2
1                    2                     3                     4
2                    3                     5                     6
3                    4                     7                     8
4                    5                     9                    10
```