# list of dictionaries containing arrays and matrices to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a list of dictionaries `a` that looks like this:

```
a = {}
a[0]={}
a[0]['first_variable']=np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
a[0]['second_variable']=np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10]])
a[1]={}
a[1]['first_variable']=np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
a[1]['second_variable']=np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10]])
```

As you can see some keys contain an array, other a matrix...

Given this  dictionary, I would like to create a dataframe that looks like this

```
a_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(columns=['dictionary','first_variable','second_variable_col1','second_variable_col2'])
a_dataframe['dictionary'] = np.array([1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2])
a_dataframe['first_variable']=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5])
a_dataframe['second_variable_col1']=np.array([1,3,5,7,9,1,3,5,7,9])
a_dataframe['second_variable_col2']=np.array([2,4,6,8,10,2,4,6,8,10])
```

This should be done in an automatic fashion...ie taking the names from the dictionary keys and in case of a matrix add col1, col2, etc...
I should also introduce a `column` (possibly in the first position) in the pandas dataframe that tells me the index of the original dictionary.. in this case the column is called `dictionary`

Can you help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
dfs = []
for c, d in a.items():
    #iterate the outer dict and reconstruct the records to handle array and matrix
    temp_dict = ({'{}_col{}'.format(k,i):e for k,v in d.items() 
                      for i,e in enumerate(np.asarray(v).T.reshape(-1,5))})
    #append the dict indicator
    temp_dict['dictionary'] = c+1
    #append the df to the df list         
    dfs.append(pd.DataFrame(temp_dict))
df = pd.concat(dfs,axis=0,ignore_index=True)
print(df)

   dictionary  first_variable_col0  second_variable_col0  second_variable_col1
0           1                    1                     1                     2
1           1                    2                     3                     4
2           1                    3                     5                     6
3           1                    4                     7                     8
4           1                    5                     9                    10
5           2                    1                     1                     2
6           2                    2                     3                     4
7           2                    3                     5                     6
8           2                    4                     7                     8
9           2                    5                     9                    10
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate and append to a list of dataframes as so:

```
lodf = []
for k in a.keys():
    tmp_df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x) for x in a[k].values()],1)
    tmp_df.insert(0,'dictionary',k)
    lodf.append(tmp_df)

pd.concat(lodf)
```

This works but it does not solve the column names issue.